# Is it possible to combine two ELF binaries into one?

Tags: linux, binary, elf

In Windows there is a utility called iexpress to which you can give two EXE files (File1.exe and File2.exe) and it will package them both into a single EXE (Result.exe). Executing Result.exe will execute File1.exe first and then File2.exe.

I am looking for a similar utility in Linux that would allow me to bind two elf binaries into one that would run the individual binaries one after the other.

Thanks

Comment: Isn't this creating self-extracting package?

Comment: shar to the rescue?

Comment: what about dynamically-loaded libraries, though?